# FFMpeg and Handbrake

Tags: ffmpeg, handbrake

I have a brilliant preset saved in Handbrake but now I need to be able to use that preset in FFMPEG.  Is there an easy way to translate or would I have to break apart the commands one by one?

Comment: Most HandBrake stuff can be done with ffmpeg, but you'd need to provide the original preset to get any help here... you probably would have to convert it 'by hand', but that shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: alternatively, use HandbrakeCLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Handbrake 0.1, If you look at the Tools > Activity Log > Encoding Log, that should provide you the details the application uses to actually perform the transcoding via command line. You would have to understand what each parameter does in Handbrake, then use the FFMPEG equivalent.